# Convertir Query mysql a sintaxis de Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hola buenos días estoy convirtiendo este Query a la forma y nomenclatura que utiliza Codeigniter.
Les comparto el Query inicial y mis avances de convertirlo a nomenclatura de Codeigniter.

> Query inicial

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT
                    parking_persons.enrollment,
                    CONCAT(parking_persons.`name`,' ',
                    parking_persons.lastName,' ',
                    IFNULL(parking_persons.lastName2, '')
                    ) AS `name`,
                    parking_career.description AS carrer,
                    parking_persons.wifi_status,
                    parking_persons.value,
                    parking_persons.instEmail,
                    parking_persons.idCareer,
                    IFNULL(radius_usergroup.groupname,'Sin Asignar') as `group`
                FROM
                parking_persons
                LEFT JOIN parking_career ON parking_career.idCareerGissa = parking_persons.idCareer
                LEFT JOIN radius_usergroup ON radius_usergroup.username = parking_persons.enrollment
                WHERE parking_persons.`status` NOT IN ('BAJA DEFINITIVA', 'INACTIVO')
                AND parking_persons.type like '%$type%'");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Intento Query nomenclatura Codeigniter.

```
$ignore = array('BAJA DEFINITIVA', 'INACTIVO');
            
            $this->db->select('pp.*, pc.description AS carrer');        
            $this->db->from('parking_persons as pp');
            $this->db->join('parking_career as pc', 'pc.idCareerGissa = pp.idCareer');
            $this->db->join('radius_usergroup as ru', 'ru.username = pp.enrollment');
            $this->db->where_not_in('pp.status', $ignore);
            $this->db->like('pp.type', $type, 'both');

            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Query no marca error, pero el problema que tengo es que la variable $type cuando trae valor tipo “PASANTE” no me trae registros y si corro el Query inicial si me trae datos. No se que parte de mi consulta este mal.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola en la consulta original estás usando `LEFT JOIN` para las relaciones. Para homologar esto debes agregar un tercer parámetro `'left'` a la función `$this->db->join`.

En tú caso:

```php
$this->db->join('parking_career as pc', 'pc.idCareerGissa = pp.idCareer', 'left');
$this->db->join('radius_usergroup as ru', 'ru.username = pp.enrollment', 'left');
```

ref: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data